# Change the structure of the footer in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have a custom theme in my magento2 website which is a child of the luma theme.

I need to add in an extra div in the footer for styling purposes but I can't find anywhere in all of the files in the site where this is being created?

```
    <footer class="page-footer">
        <div class="block ves-menu mgm-widget social-icons " id="footer-social1505690995484902180-menu">
            ... (social links) ...
        </div>
        <div class="widget block block-static-block">
           ... (you can find us) ...
        </div>
        <div class="block ves-menu mgm-widget footer-links " id="footer_menu_links1505690995532534238-menu">
            ... (footer links) ...
        </div>
        <small class="copyright">
            ... (copyright) ...
        </small>
        <div class="widget block block-static-block">
            ... (insta widget) ...
        </div>
</div>
```

This is how the footer is currently rendered, and I know how to add and remove sections to it in my layout file but I can't workout where to add my extra div in this location;

```
<footer class="page-footer">
    <div class="footer-inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create default.xml layout from the current theme and add this:

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
    <container name="footer_inner" as="footer_inner" label="Page Footer Inner" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer-inner"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

---

Container with a block text inside:

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
    <container name="footer_inner" as="footer_inner" label="Page Footer Inner" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer-inner">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="your.block.name" before="product.info.price">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<div>Content of your block.</div>]]></argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Is there anything fancy i need to deply this apart from uploading the changes to the site?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: St3phan I have added this code and upload the new xml file to my site but it is not rendering on the front end of my website. I have cleared the cached etc but still not rendering the new div

Comment: You must add anything in this container for you to see it. If it is empty, you can't see element. I add new code in my answer with a block inside the container.